# Binomial law problem

Tags: probability, statistics, binomial-theorem

We have 25 persons, 11 women and 14 men. We chose 5 people at random. X represent the number of women chosen

I'm pretty sure that this is a binomial theorem problem.

It asks for the variance :

var = npq

where

n : number of times the experiment is done

p : probability of success

q : probability of failure

var = 5 * (11/25) * (14/25)  = 1,232

Seems wrong according to manual. Any help ?

Comment: This is not a binomial problem. The count of women selected has an *hypergeometric* distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm pretty sure that this is a binomial law problem.

It is not.   You are not counting the success among a finite sequence of *independent and identically* distributed selections.   The selections are definitely codependent.

You are selecting a sample of size $n=5$ from a population of size $N=25$ with a known amount of favoured items $K=11$.   The count of women in the sample will have an [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution).

$$Y\sim \mathcal{Hyp}(N,K,n)\\[1ex] \mathsf{Var}(Y) = \dfrac{n K}{N}\dfrac{N-K}{N}\dfrac{N-n}{N-1}$$

Answer (score 2):

You should check your math again: 
$\ 5 \cdot \frac{11}{25}\cdot\frac{14}{25} \neq \ 1,232$

Also, I think you should look into the [Binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) further to get a better understanding of it and when to use it.

Comment: Or even better, why it is *not* the formula to use.  Then look up the [Hypergeometric Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution) to find the right one.

Comment: What do you mean ? My calculator gives me 1,232. And why wouldn't it be good in this situation ? Don't we either have a women or not ? Success or failure ?

Comment: Weird. We didn't see this distribution in class. Are you sure this is the only correct one to obtain an answer in this ?

Comment: Yeah ok, it seems to correspond to my problem. I'll use it but Im surprsied because like i said, we didn't see this yet in class. Maybe we will ? Who knows. Thanks again !

Comment: Well, @copper, you could be asked to solve this from first principles.  Were you?

Comment: Well, we showed me some discrete laws like Poisson, binomial, etc. Not sure if you consider this "first principles" or not. But I read some tutorial online about the hypergeometric distribution and it makes sense. My probabilities aren't always the same so it can't be binomial in this situation.

Comment: I would consider first principles to be "work out P(X = 0), P(X = 1), etc, then feed that into the original formula for variance that looks something like $Var(X) = E[(X - E[X])^2]$".

Comment: Anyway, the hypergeomtric distribution works. Im happy, thanks again !